# Apple Pay is not working with Stripe in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

In my code everything is done according to [stripe apple pay documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#set-up-apple-pay) but if user clicks on Apple Pay button from `paymentContext!.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()` nothing happens. It just pop the `PaymentOptionsViewController()` .
this is the code I'm using to show payment options view controller,

```
            let customerContext = STPCustomerContext(keyProvider: MyAPIClient())
            paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: customerContext)
            paymentContext!.hostViewController = self
            paymentContext!.paymentAmount = 500
            paymentContext!.delegate = self
            paymentContext!.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
```

It does show the apple pay button in the payment options view controller. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_wcaSFNj-X7dUaKiWdyVvVqkJtbwrbTY/view?usp=sharing) is the video demonstration of the problem.

[image]

Comment: have you Enable Apple Pay on your Stripe account?

Comment: yes. it's enabled!

Comment: setup all merchantID and certificate in apple.com?

Comment: yes. I've setup them and checked couple of times. I am wondering if Apple Pay button shows and if user clicks on it then why it's not taking me to apple pay pop up dialog. and it just pop the paymentoptionsview

Comment: Please don't post the same copy+paste question [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65518659/clicking-on-apple-pay-doesnt-work-with-stripe-integration-in-swift). Instead, edit the closed question with enough details so it gets reopened.

Comment: @Cristik my bad. thanks for pointing it out. I've deleted old one. I will keep it in mind next time

Comment: Hi Please how did you get the Apple Pay to show as a default option please. Having it as a default option is what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if user clicks on Apple Pay button from
> paymentContext!.pushPaymentOptionsViewController() nothing happens

That's normal and how it's meant to work. It's just the user selecting that they want to use Apple Pay as their payment option. The actual Apple Pay session happens when your app calls `paymentContext.requestPayment()` , which you usually do when the user hits a payment button in your app(after the PaymentOptionsViewController has closed).

https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios/basic#submit-payment

> Finally, when your user is ready to pay (e.g., they tap the Buy
> button) call requestPayment on your payment context. **It’ll display any
> required UI (such as the Apple Pay dialog)** and call the appropriate
> methods on its delegate as your user finishes their payment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for explaining it in detail. trying it now

Comment: You just saved my ass! :)

Comment: One more thing, I need help on showing the apple pay sheet in my CheckoutViewController. not here in choosing payment method view controller. can you please tell me if there is a way to do that?

Comment: You ca use the STPApplePayContext to present Apple Pay in any VC https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay#native

Comment: Hi Please how did you get the Apple Pay to show as a default option please. Having it as a default option is what I am trying to figure out.